# References for Worst-case max-min approach

Tags: reference-request, optimization, book-recommendation

I am looking for some good references for the max-min approach. Can someone kindly give me here?
Specially when the max-min problem is solved by using a slack variable and additional constraints. I know the lofberg book Minimax approaches to robust model predictive is one. Any other good reference?

Comment: Such questions are on-topic here so I removed your remark. Be sure to tag them [tag:reference-request]. The tag [tag:book-recommendation] may also be fitting, if you're specifically looking for books.

Comment: Thanks. Books will also do!

Comment: Hm, I wouldn't list my old thesis as a general reference in this topic :-) Robust optimization by Ben-Tal et. al might be a suitable start for you.